# Button control with an icon in it

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I want to show an icon in some of my buttons. Since aligning an image inside a button isn't exactly trivial, I though a user control, derived control or something would come in handy. So I googled, tried, compiled and now I came up with the following code.

Unfortunately, my properties are not bound to anything and I cannot see the text nor an image. How can I make this work? What's the missing piece? I'm using VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

XAML:

```
<Button
  x:Class="MyNS.IconButton"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Name="Icon" Width="{Binding IconSize}" Height="{Binding IconSize}" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
        <ContentPresenter/>
      </StackPanel>

      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Image.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Code file:

```cs
public partial class IconButton : Button
{
    public static DependencyProperty IconSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IconSource",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(IconButton));

    public static DependencyProperty IconSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IconSize",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(IconButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(11));

    public ImageSource IconSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(IconSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public int IconSize
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(IconSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public IconButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data binding might be the source of the issues. With those changes I was able to get an image to display in another page using your IconButton.

I made the following changes:

```
<!-- Added x:Name="_this" -->
<Button x:Class="ButtonTest.IconButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    x:Name="_this">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Background="Red">

            <!-- Bindings Changed Here -->
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=IconSource}"
                 Name="Icon"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=IconSize}"
                 Height="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=IconSize}" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
            <ContentPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Image.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Comment: With this, I see the icon, but no grey border around it and also no text. I want a plain regular grey button with text, but with an _additional_ icon besides it.

Comment: Okay, I could add the text with this: `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=_this}"/>` – But there's still no background and border and the wrong alignment.

Comment: There is no way to partially modify the ControlTemplate as you are trying to do - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx . The two ways I see you being able to accomplish this is to put a Border around the ContentPresenter and do all the visuals yourself, or, recreate it as a UserControl and have the UserControl pass on the button's events.